# Airflow | How DAG got started

Tags: airflow

Does anyone know how to get the way a DAG got started (whether it was on a scheduler or manually)? I'm using Airflow 2.1.

I have a DAG that runs on an hourly basis, but there are times that I run it manually to test something. I want to capture how the DAG got started and pass that value to a column in a table where I'm saving some data. This will allow me to filter based on scheduled or manual starts and filter test information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an execution context, such as a `python_callable` provided to a `PythonOperator` you can access to the [DagRun](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/dag-run.html) object related to the current execution:

```py
def _print_dag_run(**kwargs):
    dag_run: DagRun = kwargs["dag_run"]
    print(f"Run type: {dag_run.run_type}")
    print(f"Externally triggered ?: {dag_run.external_trigger}")
```

Logs output:

```
[2021-09-08 18:53:52,188] {taskinstance.py:1300} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=airflow
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=example_dagRun_info
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=python_task
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2021-09-07T00:00:00+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=backfill__2021-09-07T00:00:00+00:00
Run type: backfill
Externally triggered ?: False
```

`dag_run.run_type` would be: "manual", "scheduled" or "backfill". (not sure if there are others)

`external_trigger` docs:

> external_trigger (bool) -- whether this dag run is externally triggered

Also you could use jinja to access [default vairables](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/macros-ref.html#default-variables) in templated fields, there is a variable representing the `dag_run` object:

```py
    bash_task = BashOperator(
        task_id="bash_task",
        bash_command="echo dag_run type is: {{ dag_run.run_type }}",
    )
```

Full DAG:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models.dagrun import DagRun
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago


default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
}

def _print_dag_run(**kwargs):
    dag_run: DagRun = kwargs["dag_run"]

    print(f"Run type: {dag_run.run_type}")
    print(f"Externally triggered ?: {dag_run.external_trigger}")


dag = DAG(
    dag_id="example_dagRun_info",
    default_args=default_args,
    start_date=days_ago(1),
    schedule_interval="@once",
    tags=["example_dags", "params"],
    catchup=False,
)
with dag:

    python_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id="python_task",
        python_callable=_print_dag_run,
    )

    bash_task = BashOperator(
        task_id="bash_task",
        bash_command="echo dag_run type is: {{ dag_run.run_type }}",
    )
```